# Aggregation.lookup on list of ObjectIds

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I need to populate a list of children which contains ObjectId with the actual documents. I have created separate model for that.

For example:

```
(Users collection)
User document (pseudo schema):

ObjectId: _id;
String: name;
int: age;
List[ObjectId]: sports;
```

```
(Sports collection)

Sport document (pseudo schema);

ObjectId: _id;
String: name;
```

If I query student's details, I need the sports list to be populated.
I know how to use Aggregation.lookup on single id reference but dont know how to do this
for list of ids.

Answer (score 0):

$lookup automaticly if localField was array  populates the all elements
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-unwind-example